# iOS10 - ContentView Blocking Touches of UIButton in UITableView Header

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, ios10

I am in the process of updating my app to iOS10 with Swift 2.3 and Xcode 8 Beta 1 and I have found that there is a `UITableViewHeaderFooterContentView` which is blocking touches to the UIButton on my subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.

On the Xcode 8 Beta 1 simulator the UIButton works on iOS9.3 but not iOS10.

1) Is there any documentation for this?

2) How can I ensure my UI elements are on top of the new Content View in iOS10? (or allow touches through the `UITableHeaderFooterContentView`)

Thanks!

[image: Debug View Hierarchy of iOS9.3 and iOS10]

[image: TableHeader.xib]

**Table Header**

```
import UIKit

class TableHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    @IBOutlet weak var dayLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var addNewEventButton: UIButton!

}
```

**Code In View Controller**
`dateCell.addNewEventButton` is the UIButton that is no longer receiving touches in iOS10

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


    let tintColor = TintManager().getTintColour()

    let dateCell:TableHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("TableHeader") as! TableHeader

    //dateCell.bringSubviewToFront(dateCell.addNewEventButton)

    dateCell.dayLabel.text = Dates.day.uppercaseString

    dateCell.dateLabel.text = Dates.date

        dateCell.backgroundView = UIView(frame: dateCell.frame)
        dateCell.backgroundView!.backgroundColor = tintColor
        dateCell.dayLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        dateCell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        dateCell.addNewEventButton.backgroundColor = tintColor



    dateCell.addNewEventButton.tag = section
    dateCell.addNewEventButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0

    if (savedEventView.superview === self.view) {
        dateCell.addNewEventButton.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: .AllEvents)
        dateCell.addNewEventButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.userPressedAddButtonToInsertSavedEvent(_:)), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    } else {
        dateCell.addNewEventButton.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: .AllEvents)
        dateCell.addNewEventButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.userPressedAddNewEventOnTableViewHeader(_:)), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    }

    return dateCell
}
```

Comment: Please go through migration document .I think swift 3.0 introduce in Xcode 8 beta 1

Comment: It's my understanding that Swift 2.3 is still compatible in Xcode 8 Beta 1

Comment: Yes of course your understanding is right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The offending view is in fact the `contentView` of the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` (see the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewHeaderFooterView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewHeaderFooterView/contentView)).  So you should be able just to use `sendSubview(toBack:)` in order to stop it interfering with touches.

However, it seems that under iOS9 the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` fails to correctly initialise the `contentView` if the view is loaded from a NIB.  Although the `contentView` property is not optional, it is in fact nil, and you get a BAD ACCESS error if you try to access it.  Nor can you set a value for `contentView` (either in code or as an outlet in IB) because it's a read only property (*).  So the only solution I can think of is to use `#available` to conditionally include code to move the contentView to the back, if you are running on iOS 10 or newer.  I would put the relevant code into your subclass:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        self.sendSubview(toBack: contentView)
    }
}
```

(*) Indulging in wild speculation, my guess is that Apple based the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` code heavily on `UITableViewCell`.  Since IB has `UITableViewCells` in its object library (and notice these include the cell's `contentView`), it can ensure that the cell's contentView is correctly instantiated.  But since there is no `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` in the object library, there's no way to get the `contentView` loaded correctly.  Looks like they fixed it in iOS10 by instantiating an empty `contentView`.  Pity they didn't also add `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` to the library.

Comment: I had no problem with using your code with iOS9. Something like:
-(UIView*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)headerIndex {
...
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed ...
...
[headerView sendSubviewToBack:[headerView contentView]];
...
}

Comment: @Darko Interesting.  I found the problem occurred if I registered the nib and then dequeued; I didn't try loading the nib directly.  But they should both use the offending `init(coder:)` initialiser, so perhaps I need to investigate a little more.  Or it might be linked to Objective-C being more tolerant of nil values.

Comment: Possible. I tested it with iOS 9 and it works but just to be on the safe side I'm also checking iOS version before using that code, it doesn't hurt :)