# Unable to get touch events to fire on UIButtons on section headers of UITable when using IOS9 (IOS10 is fine)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

On IOS 9, touching buttons on table section header does not work, but works fine on IOS 10. This is using swift 3 both with XCode 8 and 9. I've tested with physical devices and the Simulator, always with the same result. My buttons are within a StackView, within a StackView, within the Content View, within userheader. I've found no problems with a UIButton on the section footer, but that's not where I want to use them. Everything works fine when I test on a IOS10 device or Simulator, but never on an IOS9 one.

Strangely, this seems similar to [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903764/ios10-contentview-blocking-touches-of-uibutton-in-uitableview-header) reported on stackoverflow where it works for IOS9 but *not* for IOS10

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell the problem from this description, but here's something to try.

Run the app in Xcode, then select the Xcode>Debug>View Debugging>Capture View Hierarchy menu item. Examine the views of the StackView, buttons, etc. and make sure things are laid out as you expect with nothing obscuring the tappable areas and the view sizes and positions correct.

If the buttons are in a view that has an incorrect size like a zero width, or are at an offset that puts them outside the bounds of the superview, taps won't work. But, you won't notice that unless containing views are set to clip to bounds. Otherwise, the entire button will draw and look tappable.

I can't say that this is it for sure, but with these types of issues, a likely suspect is an overlapping view stealing the touches or the touches being clipped by a superview.

Comment: Thanks @clarus for your idea.   I did try this but the stack views did appear to be laid out correctly.  I've now used the approach you suggest on other areas and it sure helps with a stack view.  This particular problem only shows itself in iOS 9 with buttons on a table header, not iOS 10 or 11.  Newer versions of XCode have helped with a lot of things but not this problem.  It persists still.  Thanks again.